# Best background process to use with adapter? - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, gridview, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to figure out which is the best background process to use for running many `Intent`s in my adapter. I have a custom `GridView`, which uploads photos from the `SD card` into an `ImageView`. I need to put click listeners on all of the photos (24 of them), so I created `Intent`s for them all that when clicked, go to another activity to display the full photo.

The code I have works, but the running time got slowed down a lot. Way too much. So now I'm trying to decide which is best to use in my adapter (if that's the best place to put my click listeners to begin with?) Would I use `AsyncTask`, `Thread`, or `IntentService`? I don't think I have tried any of them before (except in super simple tutorials), so I'm not sure which would be the best for my situation, since it's more complex. The only thing I must do is update the `UI`. So when my thumbnails in my `GridView` are clicked, they must go to an activity and update that new activity with the current photo at the position it was clicked in the `GridView`. So I basically need to put a photo `Bitmap` into the new activity's `ImageView`.

I read that `AsyncTask` is good for updating a `UI`, but I just wanted to make sure this is the right decision, before I go research it a ton. There are a lot of experienced developers on here, so I would value different perspectives. Maybe you have something I have not considered before. I am a beginner so design patterns are very hard for me still. Below is my working example of my adapter with all the `Intent`s in there.

Here is a snippet of the new activity's `ImageView` that it needs to go into (there will be 24 of these altogether). It needs to receive the `Intent`.

```
        ImageView photoView0 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo_display0);

        byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("photo0");
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
        photoView0.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

**GridViewPhotoAdapter.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection.phototab;

/**
* Created by mizu on 2/5/15.
*/
// package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/5/15.
 */
public class GridViewPhotoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PhotoGridItem> {

    public Context context;
    private int resourceId;
    Bitmap bm;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    int position;

    public GridViewPhotoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId);
        this.context = context;
        this.resourceId = layoutResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        this.position = position;


        if (row == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid_view);
            // stores holder with view
            row.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        PhotoGridItem photoGridItem = getItem(position);

        if (photoGridItem != null) {
            bm = photoGridItem.getImage();
            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

            // positioning the image in the GridView slot
            holder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(270, 270));
        }

        //Convert to bitmap to byte array, so can pass through intent
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        final byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

        // set my click listeners
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent a = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity0.class);
                        a.putExtra("photo0", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(a);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent b = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity1.class);
                        b.putExtra("photo1", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(b);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Intent c = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity2.class);
                        c.putExtra("photo2", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(c);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Intent d = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity3.class);
                        d.putExtra("photo3", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(d);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Intent e = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity4.class);
                        e.putExtra("photo4", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(e);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Intent f = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity5.class);
                        f.putExtra("photo5", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(f);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Intent g = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity6.class);
                        g.putExtra("photo6", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(g);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        Intent h = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity7.class);
                        h.putExtra("photo7", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(h);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        Intent i = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity8.class);
                        i.putExtra("photo8", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        Intent j = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity9.class);
                        j.putExtra("photo9", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(j);
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        Intent k = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity10.class);
                        k.putExtra("photo10", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(k);
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        Intent l = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity11.class);
                        l.putExtra("photo11", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(l);
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        Intent m = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity12.class);
                        m.putExtra("photo12", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(m);
                        break;
                    case 13:
                        Intent n = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity13.class);
                        n.putExtra("photo13", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(n);
                        break;
                    case 14:
                        Intent o = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity14.class);
                        o.putExtra("photo14", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(o);
                        break;
                    case 15:
                        Intent p = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity15.class);
                        context.startActivity(p);
                        break;
                    case 16:
                        Intent q = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity16.class);
                        q.putExtra("photo16", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(q);
                        break;
                    case 17:
                        Intent r = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity17.class);
                        r.putExtra("photo17", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(r);
                        break;
                    case 18:
                        Intent s = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity18.class);
                        s.putExtra("photo18", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(s);
                        break;
                    case 19:
                        Intent t = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity19.class);
                        t.putExtra("photo19", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(t);
                        break;
                    case 20:
                        Intent u = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity20.class);
                        u.putExtra("photo20", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(u);
                        break;
                    case 21:
                        Intent v = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity21.class);
                        v.putExtra("photo21", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(v);
                        break;
                    case 22:
                        Intent w = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity22.class);
                        w.putExtra("photo22", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(w);
                        break;
                    case 23:
                        Intent x = new Intent(context, PhotoActivity23.class);
                        x.putExtra("photo23", byteArray);
                        context.startActivity(x);
                        break;
                }

            }

        });

        return row;

    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever considered using caching? Google webpage @ [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#disk-cache). The idea is to use the so-called LRU Cache and also ASyncTask. Note that ASyncTask itself does not improve performance.
Here is a code snippet from the webpage that looks good to me:

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    ...
    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        final Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                getResources(), params[0], 100, 100));
        addBitmapToMemoryCache(String.valueOf(params[0]), bitmap);
        return bitmap;
    }
    ...
}
```

Note the call to `decodeSampledBitmapFromResource` and then `addBitmapToMemoryCache`, among other details on that webpage.
Well, I hope this is helpful, at least ;)